# What is the correct algorithm to see whether N points lie on the same side of a line?

Tags: algorithms, c

What I tried first was to find the equation of the line and then compare its y-intercepts with the y-intercepts of each point. I just need the proper approach to this algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick theorem, in general:

> A hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^d$ can be defined by a vector
> $\mathbf{v}$ and scalar $b$ as the set of points $\mathbf{x}$ such that $\mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{x} =
> b$. It splits the
> space $\mathbb{R}^d$ up into two half-spaces, one where $\mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{x}
> \geq b$ and one
> where $\mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{x} < b$.

So in 2D, if your line is defined by $\mathbf{v}, b$, all you have to do is check whether
either $\mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{x} \geq b$ or $\mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{x} < b$ holds for all your points $\mathbf{x}$.

---

You are probably used to a line being defined as $y = ax + b$. Note that we have
$\mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$ (beware of the bold $\mathbf{x}$ as opposed to $x$).

Thus we can rewrite to a matrix equation:

$$y = ax + b$$
$$-ax + y = b$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}-a, 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} = b$$
$$\mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{x} = b$$

and we recover the above form, where $\mathbf{v} = \begin{bmatrix}-a\\1\end{bmatrix}$.

Thus all we have to do to check is if your points are a list of $(x, y)$ pairs is if either $-ax + y \geq b$ or $-ax + y < b$ for all of them.

Comment: Hey thank you ! I didn't know anything about hyperplanes. It's fascinating that it is also a topic for ML. Now I'm much more clear.